# Embedding a ListView in an Activity in Android

Tags: android, listview, android-activity, listactivity

I have a listview at the top of my activity, does the entire activity need to extend ListActivity? Or can the main activity simply extend just Activity and a private sub-class can extend ListActivity to create the listview? I can't comprehend the best way to do this so a shove in the right direction would be awesome!

Comment: In your comment to jeffamaphone's answer, you ask about an example of how to handle `ListView` yourself...look at the source code for `ListActivity` and see how it is done. Looking at Android source is always a good way to learn. ;) http://codesearch.google.com/codesearch#uX1GffpyOZk/core/java/android/app/ListActivity.java&q=package:android.git.kernel.org%20file:android/app/ListActivity.java&l=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have `View`s in a `ListActivity` that are not `ListView`s.  If you only want one `ListView` then `ListActivity` will save you a lot of typing.  But you don't have to use it.  You can use a normal `Activity` and do all the `ListView` setup yourself.  Are you worried about something specific?

The part about having more than one `Activity` for the same UI doesn't really make any sense.

Comment: Sorry, I should say more than one View, instead of saying more than one Activity. Thank you, I am learning Android obviously.

I ask, do you mean there is no performance detriment to extending the ListActivity to the entire Class? Therefore, simply instead of my class being defined as "public class CustomerList extends Activity {", I will extend ListActivity?

Can you please show a very simple example of how you would setup ListView yourself?

Thanks so much, I appreciate the hours this saves me, sometimes the theory of Java is beyond me.

Comment: Yes, just extend `ListActivity`. I've never done it the other way, so I don't have any code to show offhand.  There is always a performance impact, but this is they way it is intended to be done, so we can assume the performance impact is negligible.